# Looking for an open source Java whois parser

Tags: java, parsing, whois

I am trying to parse whois lookups in a java based whois server and looking to use a preexisting solution.

Please note: I am **not** looking to parse whois data or query any server.

I have looked into commons-cli and JavaCC the later is promising but the idea of generated code is not attractive. My ideal solution would be a parser able to load the grammar at runtime through a file.

Example inputs I would like to parse:

```
domain example.com
host id 3223
summary registrar id 2332
```

Thanks!

Comment: Let me clarify: my application IS a whois server. I am looking to parse whois lookups myself.
Thank you, though.

Comment: Wow how could this be off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more digging I got where I wanted to go. I found [parboiled](https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled/wiki) a scala/java parser generator using [PEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar).

Big thank you to Pangea and aldridmc, I will try to be more specific in the future.

Comment: After a couple of days without a better answer. I'm accepting my own answer. Thank you to everybody who answered!

Comment: You seem to have accepted another answer instead of your own!

Answer (score 6):

There's no WHOIS parser written in Java. The only parsers currently available are written in PHP and Ruby.

I'm the author of the [Ruby WHOIS library](https://whoisrb.org/). An intelligent Ruby WHOIS client and parser.

The good news for you is that Ruby WHOIS is fully compatible with [JRuby](http://jruby.org/). It means you can use it in your Java environment as long as you use JRuby.

Comment: JRuby is an implementation of the Ruby programming language based on the JVM. It replaces the standard Ruby MRI interpreter by using the JVM.

Comment: I want to parse incoming whois commands. Your library is used to query servers. I am working on the server side!

Comment: @Stratos Please be nice, actually you can use SimoneCarletti's ruby library in java, either client side or server side is fine

Comment: Thanks Simone, do you have any information or instructions on how I would do that - ie: get your code working inside a java project using jruby?

Comment: This saved me. Ruby's Whois gem wrapped up as a Maven dependency for Java: https://github.com/ukwa/jruby-whois

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) supports multiple protocols and *whois* one of them.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the question. This library allows you to have a whois client.